# Can i still use Azure Functions v1?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I can't get my azure function to run on a higher version 2 or 3, because of dependency errors.
Can it stay in version v.1 without deprecated problems in the future?

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off-topic here, as you're asking for specific roadmap/support/sunset plans for an Azure service.

Comment: A better question here would be _How can i get rid of these dependencies and move off of v1?_.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you shouldn't. All new efforts, bug fixes, performance improvements are on new versions. Also, if you're function will depend on some other nuget package, you'll need to downgrade to a version compatible with v1. (I've been in this path and it's a hell)